# R: How to extract substring before and after certain key phrase?

Tags: r, string, substring, match

I'm trying to split a long string by several factors that occur before and after key phrases. I am able to partially split it for the first occurrence, but not for each of them. Additionally, no prior questions that deal with pattern matching have been able to answer this for me.

Sample line of text:

```r
"#1 Player A advances to third on a wild pitch. #2 Player B advances to second on an error."
```

Partial solution:

```r
gsub('((advances).*$)', '', "#1 Player A advances to third on a wild pitch. #2 Player B advances to second on an error.", ("[\\w]*) advances"))
```

This returns:

```r
"#1 Player A "
```

However, I would like:

```r
[1] "#1 Player A advances to third" [2] "#2 Player B advances to second"
```

as two separate output strings.

I am unaware of the techniques to extract the text between the phrase "advances to ..." and the player number.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that the interesting part always starts with a `#` and ends one word after `advances to`, then we can do:

```r
s <- "#1 Player A advances to third on a wild pitch. #2 Player B advances to second on an error."
regmatches(s, gregexpr("#[[:alnum:] ]+ advances to \\w+", s))
# [[1]]
# [1] "#1 Player A advances to third"  "#2 Player B advances to second"
```

(One reason I prefer the more-verbose use of `gregexpr` and `regmatches` is that it does not return "something" when "nothing" matches, unlike `gsub` unless the regex is carefully crafted.)

Comment: This is the best solution, as it doesn't need any additional library!

Comment: Thank you for the help, especially with regex, as I need to work on that more ;-) .

Answer (score 2):

Is there always a word after the number? If so, this would work:

```
library(stringr)

str_match_all(str1, "(#.*? to \\S+)")[[1]][, 2]
# [1] "#1 Player A advances to third"  "#2 Player B advances to second"
```

Comment: `library(stringr)`?

Comment: Yes, there is always a word after the number. Thank you for the help!